# Unable to deploy my django based API on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-development-server

I tried to deploy my django based api to heroku, however I have been getting the same error for the past few lifetimes

Error logs:

```
*2021-01-31T11:42:30.163925+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hospagoapi.herokuapp.com request_id=ba1f93a1-50ec-492e-b637-a3df4a1ab8d0 fwd="42.110.150.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-31T11:42:35.081501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hospagoapi.herokuapp.com request_id=abbd9954-86b9-41a6-b895-a9261ac12082 fwd="42.110.150.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-31T11:42:39.924144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/users" host=hospagoapi.herokuapp.com request_id=32eddcbd-7b44-49ef-9d1f-244f29681f05 fwd="42.110.150.136" dyno= connect= service=
 status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-31T11:42:41.717524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hospagoapi.herokuapp.com request_id=79c677cd-4a6c-4c7e-9ea5-db60a2732f2f fwd="42.110.150.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https*
```

Hospagoapi is my app name

My production git repo:
https://github.com/RachitKumar205/hospago

I apologize for any errors in my question in advance, this is my first time posting

Comment: Did you run migrations after deployment? Are your dynos running?

Comment: Yes, I did. Turns out there was a problem with the pipenv, which I still don't get. So I just removed it, made some minor modifications to the requirements file, and uploaded the code as is

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Turns out the pipenv was causing problems. I removed it, modified the requirements file and pushed the code. It started working after that.